# Какой алгоритм используется при отрисовки SVG при наложении элементов?

Tags: html, алгоритм, svg, графика, render

Предположим у нас есть 5 концентрических кругов SVG

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="90"  cy="100" cx="100" fill="green"/>
  <circle r="70"  cy="100" cx="100" fill="yellow"/>
  <circle r="50"  cy="100" cx="100" fill="blue"/>
  <circle r="30"  cy="100" cx="100" fill="violet"/>
  <circle r="10"  cy="100" cx="100" fill="orange"/>
</svg>
```

Каким образом и каким алгоритмом будет рендерится результирующая картинка?
Будет ли алгоритм сначала красить весь внешний круг, потом круг поменьше, и так далее, в результате чего точки центрального круга будут перекрашиваться 5 раз.
Либо используются какие-то оптимизации, позволяющие перекрашивать менее число раз, в идеале 1.

Я понимаю что в разных render движках могут использоваться немного разные алгоритмы. Но предполагаю, что +- подобные, но если это не так, то интересует обычное стандартное современное решение, например для Chrome.

Comment: то что Вы описали называется алгоритм художника https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо, кратко глянул ссылку и то что по ней дальше, и понял что весьма вероятно есть аппаратная оптимизация сцены, и даже если нет аппаратной то вероятно есть алгоритмы для программной оптимизации.

Comment: угу, например классический алгоритм `Occlusion Culling` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-surface_determination

Comment: @surface_determination может оформишь ответом?

Answer (score 4):

Просто мысли:

В целом в компьютерной графике применяется семейство алгоритмов так называемого "Отсечения" (Culling) или [Hidden Surfaces Determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-surface_determination) которые обеспечивают поиск примитивов, которые не попали в пирамиду видимости (**Frustum Culling**), или так или иначе не будут видны на экране (например закрыты другими объектами (**Occlusion Culling**) или являются невидимыми(задними) частями видимых объектов (**Backface Culling**)).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это дает возможность не отрисовывать эти объекты.

Есть предположение что рендеринг SVG тут ничем особо не отличился.